# Schwarz inequality for multiple integrals: $\left[\int_A f(x)g(x) \ dx\right]^2 \le \int_A f(x)^2\ dx \cdot \int_A g(x)^2\ dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

> If $f,g:A\to \mathbb{R}$ are integrable, prove the Schwarz inequality
>
> $$\left[\int_A f(x)g(x) \ dx\right]^2 \le \int_A f(x)^2\ dx \cdot
>  \int_A g(x)^2\ dx$$

This is that type of question that isn't easy to think about. I've found a solution for one dimension integrals here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1089206/166180

But now I'm working on multiple integrals, so I'm not integrating over the real line, but in blocks. $\int_A f(x) \ dx$ is defined as integrable when $\underline{\int_A} f(x) \ dx = \overline{\int_A} f(x) \ dx$, and these integrals are the sup and inf of those $M_B$ and $m_b$ things.

Does the proof I found apply for this case? It still makes sense for me when I switch $\int_a^b$ by $\int_A$, because the center of the proof is the equality $(|f|+\lambda|g|)^2 = |f|^2 + 2\lambda |f||g| + \lambda^2 |g|^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral of a non-negative, integrable function is non-negative. It follows that for any $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $\int_{A}\left(f(x)-\lambda g(x)\right)^2\,dx \geq 0$, so the discriminant of the quadratic polynomial

$$ p(\lambda) = \left(\int_A g(x)^2\,dx\right)\lambda^2 -2\left(\int_A f(x)\,g(x)\,dx\right)^2 \lambda + \left(\int_A f(x)^2\,dx\right)$$
is non-positive. Just write down the discriminant in terms of the coefficients and you are done.

---

Anyway, since in general $L^1(A)\not\subseteq L^2(A)$, I believe that the correct assumptions should be about the *square*-integrability of $f$ and $g$. Or about $f,g\in L^1(A)$, plus $\mu(A)<+\infty$.