# How to prove an integral equality.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089191/how-to-prove-cauchy-schwarz-integral-inequality/1090406#1090406), i would like to know how to prove the following inequality: $$\frac{1}{2}\int_a^b\int_a^b (f(x)g(y) - g(x)f(y))^2\,dx\,dy \\= \int_a^b f^2(x)\,dx\int_a^b g^2(x)\,dx - \left(\int_a^b f(x)g(x)\,dx\right)^2$$
 the person who gave that equality said that the integrand $\displaystyle (f(x)g(y) - g(x)f(y))^2 \ge 0$, hence the equality follows. But I never been doing something like that.
Any tips.

Comment: $$\displaystyle (f(x)g(y) - g(x)f(y))^2 \ge 0$$ is this your question ?

Comment: No why it follows

Comment: because $a^2 \geq 0$

Comment: Yeah, I know that but why the inequality follows?

Comment: LHS is an integral of a nonnegative function, hence LHS=RHS$\geqslant 0$. And RHS $\geqslant 0$ is equivalent to the inequality. Is this enough for you to catch?

Comment: Oh i see is equality, i edited my question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Left hand side: $(1/2)\int_a^b\int_a^b(f(x)g(y)-f(y)g(x))^2dxdy={(1/2)\int_a^bf(x)^2dx\int_a^bg(y)^2dy}+{(1/2)\int_a^bf(y)^2dy\int_a^bg(x)^2dx}{-\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx\int_a^bf(y)g(y)dy}$

Since $y$ is a dummy, it can be replaced by  $x$ to get right hand side..